# undefined Index Conn . I am Accessing object from one file to another file

Tags: php

```
<?php

require_once("../include/connClass.php");
// $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "hrms");

$db = new dbObj();
// var_dump($db);

$connString =  $db->getConnstring();
// var_dump($connString);

$params = $_REQUEST;

$action = isset($params['action']) != '' ? $params['action'] : '';

$objDesignationMaster = new DesignationMaster($connString);


switch($action) {
    case 'add':
            $objDesignationMaster->insertDesignationMaster($params);
            break;
    case 'edit':
            $objDesignationMaster->updateDesignationMaster($params);
            break;
    case 'delete':
            $objDesignationMaster->deleteDesignationMaster($params);
            break;
    default:
            $objDesignationMaster->getDesignationMaster($params);
    return;
}

 class DesignationMaster {
    protected $conn;
    protected $data = array();
    function __construct($connString) {
        $this->conn = $connString;
}

// public function getDesignationMaster($params) {
//     $this->data = $this->getRecords($params);
//     echo json_encode($this->data);
// }


function insertDesignationMaster($params){
    $data = array();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO department_master (dm_department)
       VALUES(
    '" . $params["txtDepartment"] . "');  ";

    // echo $sql;
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
 }




}




function getDesignationMaster($params){


}

function deleteDesignationMaster($params){


}


function updateDesignationMaster($params){

}


}

?>
```

I am Getting Error on this code I am Including Connection File From another file any idea about this. the object is created successfully connection object is not.

And here is my connection class

```
<?php

Class dbObj{

    var $servername = "localhost";
    var $username = "root";
    var $password = "";
    var $db = "hrms";
    var $conn;
    Public function getConnstring() {
    // Create connection
    $con = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->username, $this->password, 
    $this->db);

    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    }  else {
     $this->conn = $con;
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact error message and what line does it point to?

Comment: if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {    on this line getting error as Undefined variable conn  and   Call to a member function query() on a non-object .

Comment: Yeah, well, it's **`$this->conn`**, not `$conn`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if($this->conn->query($sql) === TRUE){ //$conn is not defined 

}
```

$this->conn  contains the connection itself. You defined it in the construct function

Comment: Undefined variable: con   I am getting this now and one more error is                                      Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access empty property.